# In bash, how do I open a writable file descriptor that's externally redirectable?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I'm trying to use bash to open a new descriptor for writing extra diagnostic messages. I don't want to use stderr, because stderr should only contain output from the programs called by bash. I also want my custom descriptor to be redirectable by the user.

I tried this:

```
exec 3>/dev/tty
echo foo1
echo foo2 >&2
echo foo3 >&3
```

But when I try to redirect fd 3, the output still writes to the terminal.

```
$ ./test.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null
foo3
```

Comment: A useful site [link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13082.html)

Comment: You might be able to use a [named pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple enough: If the parent shell is **not** redirecting fd 3, then `test.sh` will be redirecting fd 3 to `/dev/tty`.

```
if ! { exec 0>&3; } 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
   exec 3>/dev/tty
fi
echo foo1
echo foo2 >&2
echo foo3 >&3
```

Comment: As much as I wanted to give gregc the accept, he hasn't come back in nearly 4 weeks to clean up his answer. This one, though likely "borrowed" from gregc, is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 11):

First the parent shell sets file descriptor 3 to /dev/null
Then your program sets file descriptor 3 to /dev/tty

So your symptoms are not really surprising. 

Edit: You could check to see if fd 3 has been set:

```
if [[ ! -e /proc/$$/fd/3 ]]
then
    exec 3>/dev/tty
fi
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. The solution you removed almost worked. It's just that `-t` can only detect if the fd is connected to a terminal, not if it exists at all.

Comment: I just thought of the /proc test and then you posted it. Great minds think alike, perhaps. Unfortunately this isn't portable. Works great in Linux, but not mac. I'd give another upvote if I could.

Comment: Och well, it was worth a try.  I don't have access to a Mac.  Thanks for the kind comment.

Comment: @x-yuri I think you found another solution. This works on Linux & Mac: `bash -c 'if [[ ! -e /dev/fd/3 ]]; then echo "fd3 non-existent"; fi'` . However, it doesn't work on Solaris, not that I care too much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to check if a file descriptor has already been set using the (Bash) shell only.

```
(
# cf. "How to check if file descriptor exists?", 
# http://www.linuxmisc.com/12-unix-shell/b451b17da3906edb.htm

exec 3<<<hello

# open file descriptors get inherited by child processes, 
# so we can use a subshell to test for existence of fd 3
(exec 0>&3) 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && 
    { echo bash: fd exists; fdexists=true; } || 
    { echo bash: fd does NOT exists; fdexists=false; }

perl -e 'open(TMPOUT, ">&3") or die' 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && 
    echo perl: fd exists || echo perl: fd does NOT exist

${fdexists} && cat <&3
)
```

Comment: +1 This seems to be correct. I'll test some more. But you should separate the perl part, because it looks like it's part of the script. After reading more closely, I see you're only using it for comparison. Also, I'm not sure what the purpose of the `exec 3<<<hello` is; putting it before the `fdexists` test will make the test be true every time.

Comment: I've confirmed that this has the correct idea, but it needs cleanup. If you can take the script in my question and modify it with your solution, then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: `perl` part is an alternative solution. `exec 3<<<hello` there is for testing. Uncommenting this line has the same effect as redirecting the file descriptor from outside.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This can be done. See kaluy's answer for the simplest way.

**Original Answer**

It seems the answer is "you can't". Any descriptors created in a script don't apply to the shell which called the script.

I figured out how to do it using ruby though, if anyone is interested. See also the update using perl.

```
begin
  out = IO.new(3, 'w')
rescue Errno::EBADF, ArgumentError
  out = File.open('/dev/tty', 'w')
end
p out.fileno
out.puts "hello world"
```

Note that this obviously won't work in a daemon - it's not connected to a terminal.

UPDATE

If ruby isn't your thing, you can simply call a bash script from the ruby script. You'll need the open4 gem/library for reliable piping of output:

```
require 'open4'

# ... insert begin/rescue/end block from above

Open4.spawn('./out.sh', :out => out)
```

UPDATE 2

Here's a way using a bit of perl and mostly bash. You must make sure perl is working properly on your system, because a missing perl executable will also return a non-zero exit code.

```
perl -e 'open(TMPOUT, ">&3") or die' 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo "fd 3 wasn't open"
  exec 3>/dev/tty
else
  echo "fd 3 was open"
fi
echo foo1
echo foo2 >&2
echo foo3 >&3
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kelvin: Here's your modified script you asked for (plus some tests).

```
echo '
#!/bin/bash

# If test.sh is redirecting fd 3 to somewhere, fd 3 gets redirected to /dev/null;
# otherwise fd 3 gets redirected to /dev/tty.
#{ exec 0>&3; } 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && exec 3>&- || exec 3>/dev/tty
{ exec 0>&3; } 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && exec 3>/dev/null || exec 3>/dev/tty

echo foo1
echo foo2 >&2
echo foo3 >&3

' > test.sh

chmod +x test.sh

./test.sh
./test.sh 1>/dev/null
./test.sh 2>/dev/null
./test.sh 3>/dev/null
./test.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
./test.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null 3>&-
./test.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null
./test.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/tty

# fd 3 is opened for reading the Here String 'hello'
# test.sh should see that fd 3 has already been set by the environment
# man bash | less -Ip 'here string'
exec 3<<<hello
cat <&3
# If fd 3 is not explicitly closed, test.sh will determine fd 3 to be set.
#exec 3>&- 
./test.sh

exec 3<<<hello
./test.sh 3>&-
```

Comment: This would be best placed in your original answer by editing it.

Comment: Also, you should use your original SO account instead of a new one.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. If I run the script, redirecting fd 3 to a file, nothing gets written to it.